# Using NFC to open app and clock in and out

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc

I have an NFC tag in which i have written the NDEF data to using a 3rd party app.

The value is 0001 (a clientID) and MIMETYPE is application/vnd.com.apps.mycompany.myproject

I have added an intent filter to my login page in the manifest and when i scan the tag the app opens. which is what i want.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="application/vnd.com.apps.mycompany.myproject" />
</intent-filter>
```

I also have another activity where if the tag is scanned again it should display a message and give me the means to extract the value(clientID).

Currently when scan the tag from any other activity it goes back to the login screen which is expected. Does anyone have an idea of how to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: How do I temporarily handle an Intent in a different activity of my application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18923270/android-how-do-i-temporarily-handle-an-intent-in-a-different-activity-of-my-app)

Comment: Why not add the same intent filter to the other activity to handle it in-situ?

Comment: What would I set the action to in order to read the message value?

Comment: Leave it as NDEF_DISCOVERED, just parse the intent delivered to onNewIntent(). intent.getParcelableArrayExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_NDEF_MESSAGES);

Comment: i have put the intent in the manifest for the other activity but when i scan the tag it just reopens the first activity, if i remove the first intent from the main activity and try scanning it on the current activity it crashes with nothing in the logcat, at a loss :-)